# Locking table for other script's queries until my php script ends

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that truncates a table and re-builds it with data from a .csv file. This script has a cronjob running it every 15 minutes.

I have another script which this table's data is very important for it and this script is a bit heavy (might take the server a 10-15 seconds of calculation.

sometimes it happens that the first script happens while the second one is being processed , and returns an error. How can I "lock" this table for the time the first script is running?
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't truncate and rebuild. That's pointless. Instead rebuild into a new table, then do a quick rename of the new table to the old name, then trash the now old table:

```
CREATE TABLE _new LIKE old;
TRUNCATE _new;

LOAD DATA INFILE ... INTO _new ...;

RENAME TABLE old TO _old, _new TO old;
DROP TABLE _old;
```

You'll want to be careful to test this and make sure it doesn't leave you with no data, but the same risk here applies to the `TRUNCATE` method if it quits without finishing.